# Java add button on button when mouseover

Tags: java, jbutton, listener, mouselistener

I would like to add a JButton to another JButton on mouseover. Here is my actual code :

```
public class JFrameButton extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    main();
    }

public static void main()
    {
    new JFrameButton();
    }

public JFrameButton()
    {
    boutonExterne = new JButton("Externe");
    boutonInterne = new JButton("Interne");

    boutonExterne.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(200, 200);
    setLocation(100, 100);
    setVisible(true);
    boutonExterne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
            {
            boutonExterne.remove(boutonInterne);
            JFrameButton.this.revalidate();
            JFrameButton.this.repaint();
            }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
            JFrameButton.this.boutonExterne.add(boutonInterne, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            JFrameButton.this.revalidate();
            JFrameButton.this.repaint();
            }

        });
    this.add(boutonExterne);
    }
private JButton boutonExterne,boutonInterne;

}
```

This product this result :
[image: JButton on Jbutton]

But when my mouse is over the "Interne" button, it makes the button flash(appear and disapear).

Comment: Call `revalidate` before `repaint`. If that doesnt work post a [MCVE]

Comment: Well, since your cursor is on the `Interne` button, it's no longer considered to be in the visible area of `Externe`. So you probably get an immediate `mouseExited` event.

Comment: @Reimeus I've edit my code as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. Once you move the mouse from the content of the externalbutton over the internalbutton, that calls the mouseExit of the internal button, making your internalbutton hide.

A quick pack looks like:

```
    boutonExterne.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        boolean ignoreExit=false;

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(final MouseEvent e) {
            if (!ignoreExit) {
                boutonExterne.remove(boutonInterne);
                JFrameButton.this.revalidate();
                JFrameButton.this.repaint();
            }
            ignoreExit=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent e) {
            JFrameButton.this.boutonExterne.add(boutonInterne, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            JFrameButton.this.revalidate();
            JFrameButton.this.repaint();
            ignoreExit=true;
        }

    });
```